# How to git clone one commit snapshot of the repository?

Tags: git

I'd like to git clone one snapshot of the repo, i.e commit hash `f9105a38249fb57f7778acf3008025f2dcac2b1f`.

It's not the `--depth=1` because it is not the latest commit.

How can I do it?

---

Probably what I need is `git archive` (but it seems only available via GUI ...

Is there any commandline alternative or flags for `git archive` a remote repo on a specific commit?